# Передать 3 параметра

Tags: html, primefaces

```
<p:commandLink value="#{vars.success ? 'OK' : 'НЕ ОК'}"
               action="#{UIReportController.viewReportPage(vars.id)}">
    <f:param name="objectId" value="#{vars.id}"/>
</p:commandLink>
```

как можно передать 3 параметра ? есть ок, не ок  и нужен еще один ок, с ошибками ?

Comment: или как то вообще можно ?

Answer (score 1):

Можно в методе бина преобразовывать `vars.success` в любую удобную строку.

```
<p:commandLink value="#{vars.successStr}"...>

public String getSuccessStr(){
  if(success)
    return "ок";
  else if(...)
      return "не ок";
    else return "с ошибкой";
}
```

Или держать создать бин преобразования.

```
<p:commandLink value="#{coverter.convert(vars.success...)}"...>

public String convert(Boolean success...){
if(success)
        return "ок";
      else if(...)
          return "не ок";
        else return "с ошибкой";
}
```